# Python saying 'int' object isn't callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got a small project for my course, I am to write a program that simulates a person's bank account. 
I'll spare the talk, the code is down below, along with the commenting....

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    #This program starts by taking in a user input as shown in the While loop..
    #the 2 Methods in the class, 1 is for depositing money and the second is for a withdrawal..

    class Account:
newBal = 0
post_bal=0
def __init__(self, balance):
    self.balance = balance
def deposit(self, deposit):
    self.deposit = int(deposit)
    #newBal is the variable that takes the new Balance
    Account.newBal = self.balance + self.deposit
    print("Your Balance is now {}".format(Account.newBal))
    return Account.newBal
def withdraw(self, withdraw):
    self.withdraw = int(withdraw)
    if self.withdraw > Account.newBal:
        return "Error, we have a hard time finding that kind of money..."
    else:
        print("Withdrawal Accepted, have fun with that dough!")
        #post_bal is the variable that stores the balance with the withdrawal taken from it
        Account.post_bal = Account.newBal - self.withdraw
        return("Your Balance is now {}".format(Account.post_bal))

a = Account(balance=0)

while True:

input_1 = input("What would you like to do today? [1] Deposit, [2] Withdraw ")

if int(input_1) == 1:
    print(a.deposit(input("How much would you like to deposit? ")))
elif int(input_1) == 2:
    print(a.withdraw(input("How much would you like to withdraw? ")))
else:
    print(" I'm not too sure I understand what you're saying...")
```

With this I've been able to run a full loop successfully, depositing and amount and then withdrawing another, with all the outputs being returned. However, once I get either action for the second time in  the loop, I get the error call...

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6a19e620e3d6> in <module>
      33         print(a.deposit(input("How much would you like to deposit? ")))
      34     elif int(input_1) == 2:
 ---> 35         print(a.withdraw(input("How much would you like to withdraw? ")))
      36     else:
      37         print(" I'm not too sure I understand what you're saying...")

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong here...

Comment: You are using `withdraw` and `deposit` twice. Once as method name and then as instance attribute. When setting the attribute you will overwrite the method.

Comment: @RadheS, name all your class's variables with a leading underscore to avoid naming conflicts like this. For instance, `self._withdraw`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the withdraw to an `int` here.

```
def withdraw(self, withdraw):
    self.withdraw = int(withdraw)
```

Use a different name like

```
def withdraw(self, withdraw):
    self.withdraw_value = int(withdraw)
```

Comment: Ohhh okay I see it now. Thank you so much! I'll try it out and let you know